# Why prettier started splitting short lines?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, prettier

I used prettier for Angular project in VSCode for a few months. It worked ok-ish.

Today I upgraded Angular to v11 and the moment I've started changing my ts file (in this case I was changing file with unit tests, extension .spec.ts) and one line which has 85 characters is being split from:

```
const tblRows = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('table tr');
```

to

```
const tblRows =
      fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('table tr');
```

At the same time, a much longer line in the same file is not being split:

```
it('Loaded map descriptions should load names and set state for "Edit" buttons', () => {
```

I've started learning this more, found settings "print width", it was 80. I've changed it to 140, then to 120 - it does not make any visible difference.

[image]

I've checked another file, the line with 120 characters is not being split...

I've checked, prettier is used as a default formatted:

[image]

Please help to find the cause of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I knew the answer because I am fighting this myself too. However I *think* the reason for the long line not being split is that it is a string (not code) and there is a setting for that.

Comment: Could be a reason, but there are other tokens/characters after that string, so they could have been split...

Comment: @PeS: did you upgrade Angular recently as well?

Comment: yes. and nestjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still dunno why prettier stopped working, but today I figured out how to FORCE it working.

TBH, it's shame I could not do it earlier, the only excuse I have is that there were lots of things to learn and I was just overwhelmed.

Anyway, today I gave it another try and googled on "vscode prettier how to define line length", which led me to https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html. On this page, I've noticed that the recommended way to apply settings is via the configuration file, which is documented here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Upon reading the last link, I've just added ".prettierrc" file to the root of my project and added a single key so file looks as follow:

```
{
  "printWidth": 120
}
```

After that, prettier works like a charm.

P.S. Hate to keep my questions unanswered ;)